# Generate sets of size N+1 from sets of size N

Tags: graphs

Given a set $S$ of N-element sets, I want to generate all (N+1)-element sets (call this set $T$) such that for each element of $T$ each N-element subset is in $S$.

My current naive algorithm performs quite badly. Set $S$ ~ 100-10000 elements and $N$ ~ 5 or so.

More concretely (although perhaps more confusingly).

Let $N\in\mathbb N$ and $X$ be a set.

Let $S$ be such that for each $s\in S$ we have that $s\subseteq X$ and $|s| = N$.

Design an algorithm such that produces $$T = \{t\subseteq X:|t|=N+1 \land s\in S \,\forall\, (s\subseteq t \land |s| = N )\}$$

For Example:

Given a set $S = \{(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (2, 4)\}$ then the resulting set $T$ is $\{(1, 2, 3)\}$. as $(1, 2, 3)$ is the only 3 element set such that all 2-element subsets are in $S$.

For $N=2$ this is equivalent to finding all triangles in a graph.

Comment: I will add an example. The $\forall$ applies to any $s\in S$ that satisfies both criteria in the parenthesis

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest one possible approach::

- Build a hashtable that for each set $r$ of size $N-1$, maps to a list of elements $x$ such that $r \cup \{x\} \in S$.
- Now, for each $s \in S$, and each $r \subset s$ such that $|r|=N-1$, look $r$ up in the hashtable, find the corresponding list, and for each $x$ in the corresponding list, check whether $s \cup \{x\}$ satisfies the requirements -- specifically, whether every subset of size $N$ of $s \cup \{x\}$ is in $S$.

The running time will depend on the structure of sets in $S$.   I can give a heuristic analysis.  I suspect that often, each set $r$ will map to only a few elements $x$.  In such cases, the running time of this algorithm is something like $O(|S| \cdot N^2)$.  That ought to be fast enough for the parameters you list in the question.